# Make DIV element contain text like that of an input element?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a div element work similarly to that of an input element.

http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/6/

I was wondering how the input element achieves the ability to scroll to the side without having scrollbars? I don't want my div element expanding to multiple rows to hold content, but I did not see any CSS properties controlling this behavior on the input element.

**UPDATE:** All good solutions. Thank you guys for looking into it. It would appear that some aspects of the input element are controlled by the browser (i.e. highlight-to-scroll). It would appear difficult to emulate this functionality without use of Javascript. I've marked the first response as the solution.

Comment: Have you tried setting "white-space: nowrap;" inside your .editable, and setting a fixed height and overflow: hidden; on your wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set "white-space: nowrap;" inside your .editable div
2. After that, just set a fixed height to your #wrapper (something like 20px) and overflow: hidden;

It will work as I just tried.
The "white-space: nowrap" will avoid any line break, so you don't need to set a fixed width inside your .editable div.

Update: As for the option to select all text with your mouse, Alohci just pointed out on the comments to this post that you can add "overflow: auto;" to your .editable div and it will behave as wanted, at least on Chrome, where I just tried. Alohci also pointed to a Fiddle. Credits to him.

Comment: Seems to have the same caveat as Logans. It appears that some traits of input elements are bestowed by the browser and aren't replicable without javascript?

Comment: Yep... as far as I know, you won't be able to achieve that with a DIV-only solution... why don't you simply use another input field instead?

Comment: Yeah. It appears I am going to style the input element like my div element instead of the other way around. Was just leaving the question open as a learning exercise at this point.

Comment: I think you just missed the overflow:auto on the "editable" div. As per this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/17/

Comment: Thank you Alohci. I thought it wouldn't be possible. I'll add this to my answer and give you the credits. Thank you again. Learned another one!

Answer (score 1):

Input fields aspect and behaviour is controlled by the browser itself. You can use CSS to prevent the text from breaking:

See this [working Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/rTyyt/)!

```
.editable {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

As to scroll without using scroll-bars, you can only achieve either by using JavaScript or altering the HTML as to have an `input` disguised as a `div`:

See this [working Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/rTyyt/1/)!

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <input type="text" value="A really long string of content" />
</div>
<input type="text" value="A really long string of content" />
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
   width: 151px;
}

#wrapper > input {
   border: 0 none;
   background-color: white,
   color: black;
}
```